# How do agglutinative languages balance suffixes/affixes with separate words?

Tags: affixes, agglutination, agglutinative-languages

I spent a lot of time with ChatGPT fielding most of my agglutinative conlang questions to it, where it taught me somewhat (probably) correct stuff about mainly Turkish and Finnish, with a little Navajo and Swahili. What I'm still wondering about though (and I'm trying to [create an agglutinative language in code currently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172626/algorithm-to-figure-out-how-many-base-words-you-can-create-given-a-small-and-c)) is how agglutinative languages balance suffixes with separate words. Let's assume suffix-heavy agglutinative languages for now, like Turkish.

Turkish has a bunch of things which it puts under suffixes, but also has a bunch of things that it leaves to separate words. In my cursory glance at Finnish and Turkish, Finnish appears to have at least twice as many suffixes as Turkish, therefore it encodes more grammatical things in suffixes than in separate words, in comparison to Turkish. But even Finnish doesn't encode everything into suffixes, things still become separate words in common and/or complex cases.

So how does an agglutinative language decide or evolve to include some things as suffixes, and exclude other things. One common suffix thing is location-based stuff like "to", "from", "at", "by", "on", "in", etc.. Here's what ChatGPT says:

**Turkish**

- **"To" (toward)**: "-e", "-a"

  - Ev (house) + e = Eve (to the house)
- **"From" (originating from)**: "-den", "-dan"

  - Okul (school) + dan = Okuldan (from the school)
- **"At" (location)**: "-de", "-da"

  - İş (work) + de = İşte (at work)
- **"By" (next to)**: This concept is usually combined with the word for "side" and locative case: "-in yanında" (by the side of).

  - Deniz (sea) + in yanında = Denizin yanında (by the sea)
- **"On" (on top of)**: "-de", "-da" (similar to "at" but context differs)

  - Masa (table) + da = Masada (on the table)
- **"In" (inside)**: "-de", "-da"

  - Kutu (box) + da = Kutuda (in the box)

**Finnish**

- **"To" (toward)**: "-lle"

  - Talon (house) + lle = Talolle (to the house)
- **"From" (originating from)**: "-sta", "-stä"

  - Koulusta (from the school)
- **"At" (location)**: "-ssa", "-ssä"

  - Työssä (at work)
- **"By" (next to)**: "-lla", "-llä" (also used for "on")

  - Meren (sea) + lla = Merellä (by the sea)
- **"On" (on top of)**: "-lla", "-llä"

  - Pöydällä (on the table)
- **"In" (inside)**: "-ssa", "-ssä"

  - Laatikossa (in the box)

And here are some cases where ChatGPT says they use separate words instead of suffixes (though it says it's "rare"):

**Turkish**

- **"Yanında" (next to/beside)**:

  - "Okulun yanında" (next to the school)
- **"Karşısında" (across from/in front of)**:

  - "Parkın karşısında" (across from the park)
- **"Önünde" (in front of)**:

  - "Arabanın önünde" (in front of the car)
- **"Arkada" (behind)**:

  - "Binanın arkada" (behind the building)
- **"İçinde" (inside)**, though it also means 'in', can be used separately:

  - "Çantanın içinde" (inside the bag)

**Finnish**

- **"Vieressä" (next to/beside)**:

  - "Koulun vieressä" (next to the school)
- **"Edessä" (in front of)**:

  - "Auton edessä" (in front of the car)
- **"Takana" (behind)**:

  - "Talon takana" (behind the house)
- **"Lähellä" (near)**:

  - "Kaupan lähellä" (near the shop)
- **"Kanssa" (with)**:

  - "Ystävän kanssa" (with a friend)

So based on that (even if it's slightly or completely wrong, it demonstrates the main point), why/how do agglutinative languages end up choosing some things that become suffixes, and other things that aren't? There are probably [50-100 grammatical cases list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases), and those could all become suffixes in a hypothetical agglutinative language, in addition to suffixes for voice/tense/mood/aspect/etc.... So why choose some and not others?

Also, as a side comment, I'd be really curious to know roughly how many suffixes a production natural agglutinative language really might use. [This list of Turkish suffixes](https://cromwell-intl.com/turkish/turkish-suffixes.html) numbers around 800+ last time I counted, but it's probably not the best list for this purpose. But curious to know how many grammatical cases, how many tense, how many this, and how many that are converted into suffixes, vs. left to separate words in agglutinative languages *in general, at a high level*.

Comment: ChatGPT is a deceitful trickster that can no way be trusted 100%. Can't you see it yourself that in your “suffixes” section _Deniz**in yanında** (by the sea)_ has the same morphological structure as _Okul**un yanında** (next to the school)_ from your “separate words” section? Both phrases are in fact a noun + a postposition, the noun being in the genitive case marked by the suffix _-ın/-in/-un/-ün_, the pattern is **-in yanında** (“X's side-at”), and all your Turkish examples in the “separate words” section are of the same kind, a noun + a postposition, only the postpositions are different. >>

Comment: >> The difference between Turkish and Finnish is only in the number of their spatial-locative cases, 3 for Turkish vs 6 for Finnish. When Turkish runs out of cases, it starts using postpositions, but Finnish still has its cases left, but when Finnish runs out of its cases, too, it does exactly the same: it also starts using postpositions in a manner quite similar to that of Turkish. So, in the scope you have it in your question, the more locative cases a language has, the more different locative meanings can be expressed as one word, without any additional postpositions.

Comment: Why does English have a simple suffix (_-ed_, with variations) for the past tense, but a separate word (_will_ + infinitive) for the future when Latin has both as simple suffixes? Why is ‘behind’ a single-word preposition while ‘in front of’ isn’t? Why has Estonian used its equivalent of Finnish _-n kanssa_ ‘with’ to create a new case (_-ga_ ‘with’), while Finnish hasn’t? These kinds of questions are not really answerable. Things happen in languages because they make sense to the speakers at the time.

Comment: Languages do not choose anything. And generally, nor do their speakers, in any principled or systematic way.